# clojure classcastexception bug with nfc-tools

Tags: clojure, nfc

I use an NFC library from grundid in Clojure but I get a nasty bug when I try to write. In Java it works:

```
public class TextWriter implements NdefOperationsListener {

@Override
public void onNdefOperations(NdefOperations ndefOperations) {
    System.out.println("Formated: " + ndefOperations.isFormatted() + " Writable: " + ndefOperations.isWritable());
    if (ndefOperations.isWritable()) {
        System.out.println("Writing NDEF data...");
        TextRecord record = new TextRecord("It works!");
        if (ndefOperations.isFormatted())
            ndefOperations.writeNdefMessage(record);
        else
            ndefOperations.format(record);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Tag not writable");
}
```

It gets started with this code:

```
protected void launchDemo(NfcTagListener... listeners) throws IOException {
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = new NfcAdapter(TerminalUtils.getAvailableTerminal(), TerminalMode.INITIATOR, this);
    for (NfcTagListener tagListener : listeners)
        nfcAdapter.registerTagListener(tagListener);
    nfcAdapter.startListening();
    System.out.println("Waiting for tags, press ENTER to exit");
    System.in.read();
}
```

And this code gets launched by:

```
test.launchDemo(new MfClassicNfcTagListener(new TextWriter()));
```

Anyway this works.

The clojure code:

```
(defn ndef-writer []
  (proxy [NdefOperationsListener] []
    (onNdefOperations [ndefOperations]
                  (println (str "Formatted: " (.isFormatted ndefOperations) " Writable: " (.isWritable ndefOperations)))
                  (if (.isWritable ndefOperations)
                    (do
                      (println "Writing NDEF data...")
                      (if (.isFormatted ndefOperations)
                        (.writeNdefMessage ndefOperations test-record)
                        (.format ndefOperations test-record)))
                    (println "Tag not writable")))

(defn write-demo []
  (doto @nfc-adapter (.registerTagListener (new MfClassicNfcTagListener    (ndef-writer))))
  (.startListening @nfc-adapter)
  (println "Waiting for tag..."))

(defn write-nfc-card []
   (try
     (write-demo)
   (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e)))))
```

But when I run the clojure code I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.nfctools.ndef.wkt.records.TextRecord to [Lorg.nfctools.ndef.Record;

at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3258)

at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArg(Reflector.java:427)

at clojure.lang.Reflector.boxArgs(Reflector.java:460)

at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:58)

at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)

at duva_desktop.nfc.write$ndef_writer$fn__6403.invoke(write.clj:48)

at duva_desktop.nfc.write.proxy$java.lang.Object$NdefOperationsListener$62ccf694.onNdefOperations(Unknown Source)

at org.nfctools.mf.classic.MfClassicNfcTagListener.handleTag(MfClassicNfcTagListener.java:54)

at org.nfctools.NfcAdapter.onTag(NfcAdapter.java:81)

at org.nfctools.spi.acs.InitiatorTerminalTagScanner.handleCard(InitiatorTerminalTagScanner.java:89)

at org.nfctools.spi.acs.InitiatorTerminalTagScanner.run(InitiatorTerminalTagScanner.java:55)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I basically coded the same code, but then in Clojure and it fails because it cant cast TextRecord to Record (TextRecord extends WellKnownRecord, which extends Record) (it shouldn't try to cast anyway?)

```
(instance? Record test-record) true
```

Thanks in advance!

p.s.

```
(def test-record
  (new TextRecord "it workedddd"))
```

Comment: It could help if you provide whole stacktrace. Just a minor comment - it is consider a better practive to use reify over proxy - see stackoverflow.com/questions/5821892/why-should-i-use-reify-instead-of-proxy-in-clojure

Comment: Here ya go, tnx for helping - Will read into it (reify)

Comment: I now use reify, still doesn't work ofcourse, but didnt know about reify yet so im gonna use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with NFC, but the problem is well explained in the error message :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.nfctools.ndef.wkt.records.TextRecord to [Lorg.nfctools.ndef.Record;
```

Notice the L in front of the class name. The L means that it is an array. The method you are calling is mostly probably taking varargs, which in java means that it is array. Therefore your code works in java, but not clojure. In clojure you have to explicitly pass array, which you can do like this :

```
(into-array [test-record])
```

Comment: Damn.. thanks man! writeNdefMessage expected (Record... records) indeed, so in java it can actually get a single item or an array. Didnt know about the L being an array though, thanks for that. Thats why it wasn't that obvious for me haha. But is that a feature or a bug?

Comment: In the jvm the args to a varargs method are always an array. The java compiler hides this on invocation, the clojure compiler does not, so one is forced to construct the array. Perhaps a controversial design decision, but definitely not a bug.